# How to test the way a variable is defined? - as property or as value

Tags: javascript

We know that:
**delete** was meant to delete *properties*, not *variables*

Write a function that can detect the way a window property is defined.
**Example code:**

```
// Global scope (window)
var a='a';
b='b';
window.c='c';

// My scope (external script)
!function(){"use strict";
    var result;
    try{result=delete window.a}catch(e){result=e}finally{1&&console.log(result)}
    try{result=delete window.b}catch(e){result=e}finally{1&&console.log(result)}
    try{result=delete window.c}catch(e){result=e}finally{1&&console.log(result)}
}();

// Results:
/*
(var a) TypeError: Cannot delete property 'a' of #<Window>
(b) true
(window.c) true
*/
```

Question:
**How to test the way a variable is defined? -- as property or as value --**

Comment: Does this question answer itself?  Or what are you asking?

Comment: The example given does not explicitly answer the question. The answer should be a test statement that fit into the if() statement. that should tell how the variable was defined.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can think of is to check the `configurable` property. That would tell you if the object was defined using `var`/`let`/`const`.

```js
// Global scope (window)
var a='a';
b='b';
window.c='c';

// My scope (external script)
!function(){"use strict";
   console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'a'))
   console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'b'))
   console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'c'))
}();
```

Comment: Nice one. I'll be waiting for other option (answer), if any.

Comment: Sadly. getOwnPropertyDescriptor was not supported prior to IE8. Anyway the answer is cool.